# Number filed is not processed correctly

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I use Oracle Apex, I want that my 'display only field' is updated automatically. Well, when I use dynamic actions like this `select 5 * price from ...` or, for instance, random values, it works absolutely correctly, the field is filled with the value 5 * price (or set new random value). But when I use `select :P4_COUNT * price from`, the filed is empty. I think that the problem in `:P4_COUNT` (it is a number field) but I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Dynamic Action, look for "Items to Submit" (usually under the SQL or PL/SQL code). Put the names of items that need to be submitted to session state prior to running the code. Also, note that currently, all values in session state are strings. So it's probably best to use to_number if you need a number.